# How to check (replace) the MyFaces version used by Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, jsf-2, jar, websphere, websphere-8

After upgrading to WebSphere 8.5 I've experienced some incompatibilites in my JSF application. It is possible that they were caused by uncanonical use of JSF components, but I wanted to simply check what version is used

According to that document: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Fae%2Frovr_specs.html **WebSphere 8.5** uses **Apache MyFaces 2.0.x** (without specifying the version).

I was searching for myfaces*.jar withing WebSphere installation folder - nothing was found.

What version of MyFaces is WebSphere 8.5 using? How to find that jar withing WebSphere installation? Optionally, is it possible to replace it?

Comment: Hi , did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could add your own myfaces implementation and load that one instead. Therefor you would have to change the [classloader](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc%2Fae%2Furun_rclassloader_inst.html&resultof%3D%2522%2550%2541%2552%2545%254e%2554%255f%254c%2541%2553%2554%2522%2520) and set it to PARENT_LAST.

Older versions showed the installed JSF version during JSF initalization, however IBM probably has a customized JSF version anyways.